# validate a https URL in python without regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, url

I am trying to validate a URL from my input's which needs to validate whether it is https or not. I see many solutions with regex, urlparser, urllib

I tried different modules in python like validator-collection

```
validators.url.url(value, public=False)
url('http://foobar.dk') - returns True or False
is_url('https://foobar.dk') - returns True or False
```

but this tells me for both http and https, I want to throw an error for any URL other than "https". Is there any module to validate only https URL's in python?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a second check?

```
if not my_url.startswith("https"):
    raise ValueError(f"URL {my_url} does not starts with https")
```

Comment: I can do that, but is that the right way?

Comment: given the constraints I'm guessing it's quite alright. 
If you want a better solution, I'd go with `urllib.parse` and check for the `scheme` attribute.